# categorical product of two objects

Tags: category-theory

I know that the product of two objects $A,B$ in a category $\mathscr{C}$ is defined up to isomorphism. This means that when 
$${<}{ P,f,g}{>}\text{ and }{<}{ P',f',g'}{>}$$
are two products of $A,B$ then there exists an isomorphism 
$$\alpha:P'\longrightarrow P$$
such that
$$f'=f\circ\alpha\text{ and }g'=g\circ\alpha$$
I want to express this fact in a slightly different way. Define
$$T(A,B)=\left\{{<}{P,f,g}{>}\right\}$$
to be the set of triplets ${<}{P,f,g}{>}$ with $P$ an object of $\mathscr{C}$, $f:P\longrightarrow A$ and $g:P\longrightarrow B$. Then define a relation $\sim$ on $T(A,B)$ by setting
$${<}{P,f,g}{>}\sim {<}{P',f',g'}{>}\text{ iff }\exists\alpha:P'\longrightarrow P\text{ ISO s.t. }f'=f\circ\alpha\text{ and }g'=g\circ\alpha$$
$\sim$ is clearly an equivalence relation on $T(A,B)$. Now define the subset
$$P(A,B)$$
of $T(A,B)$ to be the set of products of $A,B$.

Conclusion: $P(A,B)$ coincides with exactly one equivalence class of triplets inside $T(A,B)$ and we can call this class $\it{the}$ product of $A,B$.

Questions:

1) I said correct or wrong things?

2) what I said is completely useless or meaningless?

3) what I said can be better expressed?

Comment: How can you call the class *the* product when it is no longer an object in your category (or a triple of an object and two morphisms)?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I don't know. That's a problem , I suppose.

Comment: What you said is in my view okay, but has only benefits for your own understanding. If it is said that products are unique up to isomorphisms then this is indeed behind it. You simply must get used to talking about **a** product (representative of your equivalence class) instead of **the** product. Keeping in mind what is behind is a good thing.

Comment: When you say "to be the set of triples" the word "set" there seems very dangerous.

Comment: @Hoot I see, maybe I should say $\mathscr{C}$ locally small

Comment: I don't think even that fixes it. You still get to choose $P$.